# Behavior of Observables and Observers in RxJava2

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

It's confusing enough that the `.subscribe()` method returns `void` if you pass it an `Observer`, but `Disposable` when passed anything else. I realize this has to do with the Reactive-Streams spec, but still…

`Observer` provides the `.onSubscribe( Disposable )` method, but as I read the ReactiveX `Observable` contract, this method may or may not be called when the `Observer` subscribes. Is this true for RxJava2? [It seems that it is only *required* to be called by `Flowable`, which uses it to notify the `Subscriber` that it's ready to accept requests.]

I've read that `.subscribeWith( Observer )` somehow addresses this issue but I'm having trouble seeing how. Evidently you can pass `DisposableObserver`, which implements `Disposable`, but what exactly is the `.dispose()` method supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this method may or may not be called when the Observer subscribes. Is this true for RxJava2?

The protocol definitions in each RxJava base class are quite clear:

Flowable via [Publisher](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#api-components):

```
onSubscribe onNext* (onError | onComplete)?
```

[Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html):

```
onSubscribe onNext* (onError | onComplete)?
```

Single:

```
onSubscribe (onSuccess | onError)?
```

[Maybe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html):

```
onSubscribe (onSuccess | onError | onComplete)?
```

[Completable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html):

```
onSubscribe (onError | onComplete)?
```

`onSubscribe` is mandatory, even in `never()`.

> I've read that .subscribeWith( Observer ) somehow addresses this issue

The definition is `S subscribeWith(S observer)` where `S extends Observer<? super T>`. It simply returns the observer or subclass of an observer provided to it.

> but what exactly is the .dispose() method supposed to do?

Disposes the `Disposable` sent through `Observer.onSubscribe` in a thread-safe manner. In alignment, the `DisposableSubscriber` cancels the `Subscription` received through `Subscriber.onSubscribe`.

Comment: Would it then be fair to say that these reactive sources do not strictly adhere to the generic ReactiveX contract here http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html ?

Comment: That documentation is for the pre RxJava 2.x implementations and is an amalgam of the various older ReactiveX variants. It hasn't been updated to fully integrate with RxJava 2.x. RxJava 2.x derives itself from the [Reactive Streams](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm#reactive-streams) specification. There are some overlaps but there are differences.